# conversion of dimension of streamlit canvas image

Tags: python, neural-network, streamlit

I am building a digit-recognizer neural network model on python. when I am feeding the testing image through a stream-lit canvas into the model I have to convert the 3D image into 2D and then to (1,28,28). but after that my model cannot predict the image even if it has a 97% accuracy. Can somebody help me. this is my code:-

```
%%writefile app.py
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_drawable_canvas import st_canvas
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras
# Specify canvas parameters in application
stroke_width = st.sidebar.slider("Stroke width: ", 1, 25, 3)
stroke_color = '#ffffff'
bg_color = '#000000'
drawing_mode = st.sidebar.selectbox(
    "Drawing tool:", ("freedraw", "line", "rect", "circle", "transform")
)
realtime_update = st.sidebar.checkbox("Update in realtime", True)
model_new=keras.models.load_model('digitrecognizer_mnist.hdf5')

# Create a canvas component
canvas_result = st_canvas(
    fill_color="#000000",  # Fixed fill color with some opacity
    stroke_width=stroke_width,
    stroke_color=stroke_color,
    background_color=bg_color,
    update_streamlit=realtime_update,
    height=150,width=150,
    drawing_mode=drawing_mode,
    key="canvas",
)
import cv2 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
a=np.ones([150,150],dtype='uint8')*255
st.write(canvas_result.image_data.shape)
img=np.asarray(canvas_result.image_data).astype(np.uint8)
img.resize((28,28))
st.write(img.shape)
img=img.reshape(1,28,28)
k=model_new.predict_classes(img)[0]
if st.button('PREDICT'):
  st.write('Predicted value is') 
  st.write(k)
```

Comment: Please, provide code you have this far. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

```
if canvas_result.image_data is not None:
    img=cv2.resize(canvas_result.image_data.astype(np.uint8),(28,28))
    img_rescalling= (cv2.resize(img, dsize=(200,200),interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST))
    
    if st.button("Predict"):
      x_img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      y_pred=model.predict(x_img.reshape(1,28,28))
      y_pred=np.argmax(y_pred,axis=1)
      st.title(y_pred[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PIL.Image` to reshape the image. In my case, I transform the `image_date` into an Image, resize it and then transform it into an array of one dimension, containing the color of the pixel (as it is in gray scale, the value of R, G and B are the same):

```
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np
    pic = Image.fromarray(image_data, 'RGBA').convert('L')
    pic.thumbnail((28, 28), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    arr = np.asarray(pic)
    arr = arr.flatten()
```

> `thumbnail` method use proportion to resize the image, keep this is in mind

If you do `arr.shape`, you get 784 (28 x 28)

```
    arr.shape
    >> (784)
```